# WPF Timer and UI Update Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, timer

I have a problem in my application, it does not correctly update the UI after changing a custom property, that is binded to a GridView Column using `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding property}"`.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="downloadList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="0,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="810" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" MouseDoubleClick="DownloadList_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="DownloadGridView">
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="c_filename" Header="File name" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=downloadList_fileName_Width, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fileName}" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="c_size" Header="Size" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=downloadList_size_Width, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding formattedFileSize}" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="c_downloaded" Header="Downloaded" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=downloadList_downloaded_Width, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sizeProgress}" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="c_status" Header="Status" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=downloadList_status_Width, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is my custom class with properties:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DownloadManager
{
public class DownloadItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _filepath;
    public string filePath
    {
        get { return _filepath; }
        set
        {
            _filepath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _sizeprogress;
    public int sizeProgress
    {
        get { return _sizeprogress; }
        set
        {
            _sizeprogress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

// and so on...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

}
}
```

The timer: **Edited to show a real example of what i'm trying to do**

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer updateTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(updateTimer_Tick);
updateTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);


private void updateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DownloadItem item in downloadList.Items)
    {
        long BytesReceived = item.filePath.Length;
        item.sizeProgress = BytesReceived;
    }
}
```

`item.filePath` contain the Path of a file being downloaded, using a `FileStream` to write it.

My goal is to read the file size every second and display it.

**The problem:** The UI, in this case the column binded to `sizeProgress`, is being Updated only one time, just at the first tick, and then nothing. The app still run without any exception..

And i really do not know what could be the issue.

If you need more Information / Code tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried binding an actual collection to the `ListView` instead of manipulating the `ListView.Items` directly. Bindins an `ObservableCollection<DownloadItem>` may behave a lot more reliably

Comment: @sa_ddam213 No i didn't, I will take a look at what you suggested,   But i don't think this is the problem. I have other function that update the Items inside the listview and they do work correctly (UI updated aswell).

Comment: Have you stuck a breakpoint in the tick handler? Is the handler being called more than once? Is there an exception being thrown somewhere on another thread which is messing things up (ctrl-alt-e in VS, check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions: Thrown")?

Comment: It could be that the UpdateSourceTrigger is not defaulting to `PropertyChanged` for `int`, maybe try `{Binding sizeProgress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`, and it may be a good idea to make `sizeProgress` a `long` to match the data outerwise it could overflow.

Comment: @canton7 yes i have CLR Exceptions being thrown, and the handler is being called every second (tested using simple MessageBox)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 The binding is not the problem, because it gets updated at the first timer tick. The only thing that i can think atm is that there is some issue getting the file size..

Comment: @WiS3 so the loop is definitely running, that property is definitely being assigned to each time, but the binding isn't updating the GridViewColumn? Stick a no-op converter in there, put a breakpoint/Debug.WriteLine in the converter, and make sure it's being called on each iteration with the right value.

Comment: @canton7 I've found the problem. The UI it's actually being updated, but the value of the property it is the same. I don't know if delete this question and ask a new one about the *real* problem (Getting correctly the file size) or Edit this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long BytesReceived = item.filePath.Length;
```

Er, that's the length of the `string` containing the path to the file, not the length of the file itself.